# How do I prevent an app from using my api key?

Tags: c#, api, ssl, encryption

My organization has a Win32 application that is written in the "fat client" style.  I am writing a C# Client / Server solution that will replace this Win32 application.  I am using ASP.NET MVC for the server and the client is a WPF application.  I did my own custom implementation of the OAuth 2 spec.  I am planning on creating a Restful API, and I want for not only my client to use it, but also allow 3rd parties to use it as well.

Every app will have an api key issued to it including the official client, but the official client's api key should be allowed additional api scopes (permissions) that 3rd party users aren't allowed to use.  It is pretty obvious how to solve this but if you consider not everyone plays nicely, you have to ask "What would stop someone from just pretending like they are the official client and using it's api key?"  Communication will be encrypted, but the server is not in the cloud or anything like that where we could control it.  Our customers install the servers on their own machines and they will more than likely have access to the server application's SSL cert.  Once you have that you can easily write an app that would run on our customer's machine that could glean the API key and secret from the official client app and use that info to request tokens from the server as if you were the official client.

I am planning on self signing the default key that the server uses and I could try and hide it in the application, but that really is just obfuscation.  Besides, I wanted to allow users to provide their own SSL certs so browser based 3rd party applications wouldn't have issues with the browsers complaining that they are trying to communicate with on a self-signed SSL channel.

Is there anything I can do?  Here are my choices as I see it:

1) I can set it up so that only SSL certs provided by us can be used and we hide them on disk encrypted using a secret that is obfuscated in the application code.  We then just hope no one bothers to take the time to dig through our .net assemblies to find the secret used to encrypt/decrypt the certs on disk.

2) We allow them to provide certs so that we don't need to be involved with that process at all when they want to use a signed cert (we don't want to be in the cert business). Now we can't even hide behind obfuscation so if someone wants it, then the official client's API key and secret is easily obtainable.

Neither seems very desirable to me.  Option 1 makes us have to request addition funds from them and manage SSL certs when self-signed doesn't work for them and in the end if someone really wants them they can still take the time to get them.  Option 2 just makes it super easy to steal the official client's secret.

Comment: Fundamentally, any sensitive credential (such as certificate private key, or otherwise) that is distributed with your application remains unprotected.  I would especially refrain from distributing any credential with the client application and, instead, resort to a method of authentication that specifically does not use any stored credential (such as username and password entry) and leave any authorization decisions to the server.  Essentially, if the client application were to be somehow provisioned upfront, it can always be exploited.

Comment: Ultimately, secrets will be kept - we just need to decide where the best place is to keep them, and make peace with the fact that they'll always remain vulnerable.

Comment: The client pretty much must be able to keep and provide a secret.  I understand there is no iron clad way to do this.  I don't think the OAuth 2 spec strictly requires a secret to be sent with the API key when requesting access tokens, but it would be kind of foolish to allow that.  The OAuth 2 process does imply that user / password is part of the picture, but that is separate from api authentication.  You ask for token with your api key and secret, it redirects you to a page to display to user for user/pass , they then decide whether to grant the your app access to requested resources.

Comment: OAuth 2 doesn't say how to issue keys or secrets.  Essentially we will provide an key and secret to developers which are needed to get the access token which is passed to the server for each request.  You could issue keys and not require secrets, but that allows 3rd parties to easily spoof other apps.  Imagine no secret and a popular 3rd party plugin.  Get that API key and be granted access to everything the good plugin was approved for by their admins.  Problem is our client is a consumer of the API too and our app can't hide behind our firewall.  I think obfuscation is the only answer : /

Comment: Would it feasible for you to offload the OAuth2 authentication to some middleware running closer to the server burdened with storing the sensitive app secret, in exchange for a valid user name and password (or other unsaved credential) from the client. You may either think of it as your "key vault", much like banks do with HSMs (Hardware Security Modules), or it may go as far as doing the OAuth2 authentication on the client's behalf.

Answer (score 0):

Reasons to want to limit unofficial Apps:
1.  Discourage clones
A.  Tell people not do it.  Have a lawyer send cease and desist letters to authors of popular apps (and to anyone helping distribute them).  Intermittently download them and alter the client/server code so that the popular apps will break.  For added discouragement, temporarily ban any users who used the popular app.  Authors will mostly give up on cloning your app; temporarily banning users will kill their install base.  This is not great for your reputation.

2.  Prevent unauthorized behavior.
A.  Any behavior allowed by the official app should be allowed by the custom app.  Whatever scenario you are worried about, block it server-side so that neither app can do it.

You can try to hide credentials (code obfuscation, hidden credentials, etc.), but this is only raises the cost/difficulty.  This is often enough to discourage code theft (no need to make code theft impossible; it is sufficient to make it more difficult than copying it by hand).  However, users who want to use your api in unsupported ways can work around this.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is simple. each instance of you app should have its own unique key effectively a user sign up. You then ban users who infringe your rules. in this case signing in with a non authorised client. should be pretty easy to detect by pushing updates more frequently than  it would be cost effective to reverse engineer them. Much like punk buster or other anti cheating tech